# Replacing characters from multiple files with regex and Powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to change _ to - in all .md files from folder FOO. The code below does what I need but I don't how to save results in folder FOO or some other...

```
$mdfiles = gci *.md
gc $mdfiles | ForEach-Object {if ( $_ -match '^!') {$_ -replace '_', '-'} else {$_}} | out-file ...
```

Comment: Did you try checking the examples [from the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.2)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Santiago,
Yes, I checked official documentation but there I can't find how to output multiple (100+) files after replacing to 100+ same or new files, not to single one. 

This command works fine if I try to change only one file.
`gc .\foo.md | ForEach-Object {if ( $_ -match '^!') {$_ -replace '_', '-'} else {$_}} | out-file foo1.md`

My last atempt was this, but this command also create only one file
`gc $mdfiles | ForEach-Object {if ( $_ -match '^!') {$_ -replace '_', '-'} else {$_}} | out-file  $(".\" + $mdfiles.basename + "-new.md")`

Answer (score 1):

A `ForEach-Object` is needed to iterate over the file names as well. Ternary expressions are in PowerShell Core, but I am not sure about Windows PowerShell. This is not tested, but might give a start.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path '.' -Filter '*.md' |
    ForEach-Object {
        $OutFile = ".\foo\$($_.Name)"
        Get-Content -Path $_.FullName |
            ForEach-Object { ($_ -match '^!') ? ($_ -replace '_','-') : ($_) } |
            Out-File -FilePath $OutFile
    }
```

Also, it is bad practice to use alias commands in a stored script.